# whether Java thread execution for a single instruction based on native CPU or bytecode

Tags: java, multithreading, assembly, jvm, jit

First of all, I might not describe the problem clearly, please leave a comment since I have limited knowledge about the case I'm asking about

From OCA/OCP Java® SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide

> count++ statement into multiple Java bytecode instructions, you really
>   have no control over what native instructions are executed. The JIT
>   (Just In Time compiler)– based nature of most Java runtime
>   environments means you don't know when or if the count++ statement
>   will be translated to native CPU instructions and whether it ends up
>   as a single instruction or several.

My question is, is it different if a statement is translated to the native CPU instruction by JIT or still on java bytecode in terms of multi-threading executing the instructions?

I'm under impression that the thread works on native CPU instructions level, not bytecode instructions level, so even if JIT translates a method to native CPU instruction or not, the low-level thread eventually will execute the native CPU instructions of the translated bytecode.
But if that is true, **this means that the quote is wrong since finally the thread will work with native cpu instructions apart from if JIT translates that code to native cpu or not, could you please confirm?**

For ex, if c++ statement from `void example(){int c=0;c++;}`  is 1 instruction on bytecode, but 3 instructions on native CPU, and the JIT doesn't translate the method example into native CPU instructions, and thread T executes the statements c++, **will that statement will be executed as bytecode instruction (1 instruction) or native CPU(3 instructions)?**

**Anyone could provide me resources about the topic I'm asking about?**

Comment: So the question is the concurrency properties change depending ona

Comment: I can't understand your question. Obviously CPU executes only native instructions, so JIT or non-JIT the bytecode will always end up translated into native instructions. In the context of MT even if `c++` is translated into a single instruction (say `inc DWORD [rbp]` on x86) it doesn't guarantee any atomicity nor ordering, so MT soundness is not about the number of instructions.

Comment: Your English is difficult to understand. And your questions seem to be full of incorrect assumptions, which makes it even more difficult to understand what you actually want. E.g. *"JIT translates a method to bytecode"* implies that bytecode is produced by the JITs, but they consume it, so the rest of the question doesn't even make sense because it is founded on wrong assumptions.

Comment: Just to clarify: if `c` is a local variable, like in your example, it is impossible to be seen by a different thread, so it doesn’t matter whether it is updated in one instruction or multiple instructions. For the records, it will be one byte code instruction, but *zero* native instruction after JIT processing, as the result is not used at all. If you apply the `++` operator to a heap variable, it will consist of multiple byte code instructions, not that it matters, but it’s perfectly possible that the JIT tears apart the read and write parts of the operation and fuses them with other updates.

Comment: In the absence of proper thread synchronization, the optimized code may use a previously read value, increment it (in a CPU register) and use it without writing it to the heap memory at all, to only write a net result after processing a long chain of operations. The result of the executing thread still is the same (only less execution time), but other threads may encounter the weirdest results if accessing the same variables without proper synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is right. You don't have control over what native instructions are executed. There are a lot of architectures and VM types and you can't be sure about all of them.

As for the bytecode for your particular case, if you're curious you can try using `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` and other [Diagnostic flags](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) to play with.